# how to get random port for configured listener in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-test, undertow

I am able to run this port randomly while making ***Server.http.port=0*** in ***@SpringBootTest*** using properties attribute but how to get random value of  server.http.port property?

```
@Configuration
public class PortConfig {

    @Value("${server.http.port}")
    private int httpPort;

    @Bean
    public UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.addBuilderCustomizers(new UndertowBuilderCustomizer() {

            @Override
            public void customize(Undertow.Builder builder) {
                builder.addHttpListener(httpPort, "0.0.0.0");
            }

        });
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a random value for **httpPort** or the question is about how to configure the property ?

Comment: @R.G, need to get random value of httpPort.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your Spring Boot version:

1) For version >= 2.0.0 use [@org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/web/server/LocalServerPort.html) annotation to inject the port that got allocated at runtime:

```
 @LocalServerPort
 private int port;
```

2) For all versions:

```
@Value("${local.server.port}")
private int port;
```

Comment: Actually i need random port for my configured listener as you can see configuration above and setting port by key "server.http.port" from properties file. but above provided solutions for getting random port for server.port=0  property. so my need is to get random port for server.http.port=0?. so that will be place hoder in @value to get value?

Comment: @DevendraSingh I don't thing I understand what you need. A valid available random port?

Comment: thank you@Eugen Covaci, I  have configured my application to run on two ports as setting port value using server.port and server.http.port keys from application.properties file. so, using @LocalServerPort, i am able to get random port value for key server.port. but i need random value for another port as i have configured using server.http.port key. I have tried using @Value("${local.server.http.port}") but did not work out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use random port by defining **server.port=0** in application.properties file and get by

```
  @org.springframework.boot.web.server.LocalServerPort
  private int localPort;
```

Comment: I need random port  defined by server.http.port=0 in application.properties file?

Comment: May be can use like this      port=${server.http.port}

Comment: thanks @Vikram, but i have tried this, but getting port value 0 and aslo tried port=${local.server.http.port}, but giving exception like wrong placeholder name